# Which is best one javaScript every() / for loop case

Tags: javascript

I am little bit confused about every() and forloop. Which is the best loop for array elements with some condition. For example:

```
function isBigEnough(element, index, array) {
  return element >= 10;
}

[12, 5, 8, 130, 44].every(isBigEnough);   // false
[12, 54, 18, 130, 44].every(isBigEnough); // true
```

or

```
var arr = [12, 5, 8, 130, 44];
for(i =0 ; i<arr.length; i++) {
    if(arr[i] >= 10)
        console.log(arr[i])
}
```

Which is one best performance for check/sort out the element from array. I hope you to clear my doubts.

Comment: for is always better. every inturn it finds the length and then it will loop each element with  a function call.

Answer (score 0):

first thing instead of every use some function, it is more apt in your case.

secondly using asynchronous **native array functions** is always better in terms of code readability as well as performance when you app scales.
Plus they have additional benefit when it comes to object oriented implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The best is to ignore issues like that *unless you have a good reason to suspect that performance is going to be a factor*.

Use the cleanest, most readable approach by default. Only consider performance when you think it's likely this is going to be a bottle-neck (and a bother). Iterating over ten elements isn't - and even then, the answer is that you need to *profile* the time for yourself; just try both the possibilities, measure the difference, and if it's big enough, pick the faster one. Saving 5% of run time isn't usually worth the costs.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for the simplest approach and that is with the for loop.

The Every loop is something new that not all browsers are compatible with and this mean you will add more code to check this.

Therefore the for loop is the best idea to use .

Thanks